# Custom field type won't postback

Tags: 2007, custom-field-types, development, postback

I've been trying to build a custom field type.
It's basically a set of cascading dropdowns, where the values of the second dropdown are taken from another list based on the selected value in the first dropdown.
I have followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684919.aspx) tutorial, and based my custom field type on that.
The problem I'm having is that my first dropdown refuses to do a postback (at all).

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 namespace CaesarDropDown
{   
[CLSCompliant(false)]
[Guid("0a876b22-e0c7-4a4e-a434-68c3232266dc")]
public class CeasarDropDownFieldControl : BaseFieldControl
{
    private DropDownList parentList;
    private DropDownList childList;
    private TextBox box;
    private SPDataSource dataSource;
    private SPSite site;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicate whether our field should be shown as a new section or appended to the end of the preceding section
    /// </summary>
    public bool DisplayAsNewSection
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        site = SPContext.GetContext(this.Context).Site;
        dataSource = new SPDataSource();
        dataSource.List = site.RootWeb.Lists["Categorieën"];

        parentList = new DropDownList();

        this.parentList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(parent_SelectedIndexChanged);
        this.parentList.AutoPostBack = true;

        this.parentList.DataSource = dataSource;
        this.parentList.DataTextField = "Title";
        this.parentList.DataValueField = "Categorie";
        this.parentList.DataBind();
        this.parentList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));

        this.childList = new DropDownList();
        this.box = new TextBox();
        this.box.Text = this.ControlMode.ToString();
    }

    void parent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureChildControls();

        SPDataSource ds = new SPDataSource();
        ds.List = site.RootWeb.Lists["Applicaties"]; // Temporary, get the correct list from the first dropdown here later
        this.childList.DataSource = ds;
        this.childList.DataBind();
        this.childList.Visible = false;
    }


    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return this.parentList.SelectedValue;
        }

        set
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            this.parentList.SelectedValue = (string)this.ItemFieldValue;
            SPDataSource ds = new SPDataSource();
            ds.List = site.RootWeb.Lists["Applicaties"];                
            this.childList.DataSource = ds;
        }
    }

    protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        return base.OnBubbleEvent(sender, e);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {           
        this.parentList.RenderControl(output);
        this.childList.RenderControl(output);
        this.box.RenderControl(output);
    }

}
```

}

Whenever I select an option in the first list, there is **no** postback, the page doesn't refresh (like it should) and thus the SelectedIndexChanged method is not firing.
I've been trying everything now, but I just cannot get my dropdown to postback...
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that it does not work is that you are overriding the Render() method. Remove that override and add the following to your CreateChildControls:

```
this.Controls.Add(parentList);
this.Controls.Add(childList);
this.Controls.Add(box);
```

If you do this then your controls will be registered in the control tree and get a valid control name. This registration is required to get postbacks to work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, That was the culprit!
When I look at it, it's quite logical actually. 
I mixed up some different tutorials/code snippets...

Answer (score 0):

I havent looked at your code, but i implemented this functionality before so i know theres a working version available on codeplex that you might either use instead or look for inspiration in: http://cascddlistwithfilter.codeplex.com/

Comment: That is true, but that requires me to have ALL the data in the second dropdown in 1 list and filter that one on runtime. I would like to have it take the items in the second dropdown from a different list depending on the selected item in the first.

I have checked the code and can't find any differences that could cause my postback not to work tho :(